# How do I grow sweet potatoes in a pot?

Tags: vegetables, containers, root-vegetables, sweet-potato

I planted some attractive [sweet potato vines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_potato) in a 6 inch deep pot -- about 1.5 ft in diameter. I didn't expect them to grow extensively. However, with watering regularly, they certainly are growing like crazy. I'm wondering if I should take the time to try to harvest sweet potatoes from them.

Is it feasible to harvest an appreciable amount of sweet potato from the pot? Or would it only be feasible to grow sweet potatoes in a more traditional vegetable garden?

Answer (score 13):

The growth that you are seeing is normal for sweet potatoes. But what you want is sweet potatoes, not vines. The container that you are using is too small for any significant growth of roots. You may get a couple tiny potatoes.

Of course growing in the ground will work much better.

However you can certainly grow them in a container. Try a five gallon (minimum) plastic bucket, like the ones that hold paint with the handle. This will give the plants room to develop some sweet potatoes. **The bigger the container the more root growth**.

Go to [Gardening Directions](http://www.gardeningdirections.com/) and follow the directions for [planting tomatoes in a five gallon bucket](http://www.gardeningdirections.com/learn/vegetable-gardening/106-growing-container-tomatoes-in-your-vegetable-garden).